# Subject.subscribe not working outside constructor

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular7

I have a simple service.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class XmlService {
    items$: Subject<Item[]> = new Subject<Item[]>();

    constructor() {
        setTimeout(() => this.items.next([{age: '20'}]), 4000);
    }
}
```

After setting it up in the `app.module.ts` and the corresponding files, i come to `app.component.ts`, which I have the following setup:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private xmlService: XmlService) {
        // Try 1. It worked fine
        xmlService.items$.subscribe(items => console.log(items));
    }

    calledFromClick() {
        // Try 2. Does not work at all even though the method is clicked
        this.xmlService.items$.subscribe(items => console.log(items));
    }
}
```

Is there any reason why try 1 worked and try 2 did not work? I have a feeling this question is a duplicate of another question but I can't figure out the right way to ask this question.

Counting on your help

Comment: did you click within the first 4 seconds? If you clicked after the timeout was triggered, you will not get any events, I guess

Comment: can you call the calledFromClick from ngonInit and try again let me know if it is working or not

Comment: @TobiasGassmann. I clicked way after the 4 seconds

Comment: It does work on `ngOnInit`. I just wanted to know if there is a reason why it doesn't work outside ngOnInit and constructor

Comment: In order to be notified, you must subscribe before `this.items.next()` is called. In the present case, you must subscribe within the first 4 seconds, as mentioned by Tobias Gassmann. Try clicking the button earlier, or increase the `setTimeout` delay.

Comment: In case you want to be able to wait longer than 4 seconds you could use a ReplaySubject

Comment: or maybe better a BehaviourSubject

Comment: The answer is what @ConnorsFan gave. I have to subscribe before this.items.next() is called

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** At first I suggested a ReplaySubject, but a BehaviorSubject would be better I guess

https://medium.com/@luukgruijs/understanding-rxjs-behaviorsubject-replaysubject-and-asyncsubject-8cc061f1cfc0

Your could use a BehaviorSubject like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class XmlService {
    items$: BehaviorSubject<Item[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Item[]>();

    constructor() {
        setTimeout(() => this.items.next([{age: '20'}]), 4000);
    }
}
```

The **BehaviourSubject** stores its last value, so that subscribers will always get the latest value even if it has been emitted before the subscribe-method was called.